# Reshaping data table for plotting that has variable name and value int he same row

Tags: r

I'm in the process of building a Shiny app but need help with some data transformation in order to generate the plot. The SQL query and filter gives me the desired result, but the shape of the data is presenting a roadblock as everything is on a single row and the desired feature names are inside the columns. Currently the data table is shaped as follows

| aName | aValue | bName | bValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FeatureNameA | FeatureValueA | FeatureNameB | FeatureValueB |

My goal is to have a Feature Importance plot but I don't want the feature labels to be the generic names (aName, bName), I'd like for them to be FeatureNameA and tied to FeatureValueA etc.

Thank you!

I tried melt() and t() but these are not getting the desired results. The desired result would be a reshaped table that looks like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| FeatureNameA | FeatureValueA |
| FeatureNameB | FeatureValueB |

Hoping I can get help on writing a function to transform the table to get the desired result for a bar plot.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = everything(), 
    names_to = c(".value"), names_pattern = ".(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Name         Value        
  <chr>        <chr>        
1 FeatureNameA FeatureValueA
2 FeatureNameB FeatureValueB
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
 data.frame(Name = unlist(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
    Value = unlist(df1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(aName = "FeatureNameA", aValue = "FeatureValueA", 
    bName = "FeatureNameB", bValue = "FeatureValueB"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
data.table::rbindlist(
  split.default(mydata, f = gsub("(.).*", "\\1", names(mydata))))

#           aName        aValue
# 1: FeatureNameA FeatureValueA
# 2: FeatureNameB FeatureValueB
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df1),,patterns('Name','Value'))

   variable       value1        value2
1:        1 FeatureNameA FeatureValueA
2:        2 FeatureNameB FeatureValueB
```